# Printing message on Console without using main() method

Tags: java

I was asked this question in an interview.

How to print message on console without using `main()` method?

Comment: How would you start you're application without a main method?

Comment: I cannot see this as a good interview question. Surely you want to test the applicant's problem solving ability, not knowledge of little used aspects of Java?

Comment: @CallumRogers +1 trivia are the worst kind of questions, anyone who ask those questions doesn't deserve to be my boss.

Comment: In Bash, just type 'echo <message>'. You should get extra points for doing the simplest thing possible too.

Comment: Not possible in/after Java7 as main() method is looked up prior to loading classes.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
public class Foo {
    static {
         System.out.println("Message");
         System.exit(0);
    } 
}
```

The `System.exit(0)` exits program before the jvm starts to look for `main()`

<sub>(Note: This works only with java 6. Even if it compiles with JDK 7's `javac` it cannot be run with its `java`, because it expects a `main(String[])` method.)</sub>

Comment: @Roflcoptr `$ java Foo` just like any other

Comment: @Roflcoptr `java -cp . Foo` like a program with main. ;)

Comment: @Roflcoptr just compile the class and run `java Foo` it will load the class, print the message; and we exit before it starts to find the entry point for execution.

Comment: @BalaR I've copied your code into a file `Foo.java`. Called `javac Foo.java` and tried to run it with `java Foo` / `java -cp . Foo`. I got: `Error: Main method not found in class Foo, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)`. Using JDK 7 (using JDK 6 it prints another error similar to this). Where's the catch? Oh yeah, and I don't exactly care about this *Ideone* thing spouts out.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert You're doing something wrong - maybe you mis-capitalized the class name in the file?  It works for me with java 1.6.0_23.

Comment: @ErickRobertson OK. I know. I compile it with JDK but I can run it only with a JRE. However if I compile it with JDK 7 I cannot run it no matter what. Only with JDK 6.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert: May be you missed that `System.exit(0);`, since the JVM is somehow looking for the `main` method.

Comment: @BalaR OK. I got it finally. Compiling it with JDK 6's `javac` I can run it with JRE/JDK 6's `java` but JRE/JDK 7's `java` won't run it. Compiling it with JDK 7's `javac` and you can't run it with nothing. Please update your answer. My comments before were too rash, however I knew that _something_ was off.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal updated note and removed dead link as I could not find any online java 6 compiler/executor to update to. This method requires java 6 which was old when I wrote this post but is ancient now.

Comment: @BalaR yeah me too did not find any java 6 compiler otherwise I could have updated the link myself. No worries. :-)

Comment: And without using 'static'? Is it possible?

Answer (score 12):

```
public final class Main {
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The static block is first executed as soon as the class is loaded before the `main();` method is invoked and therefore before `main()` is called, `System.exit(0)` initiates VM shut down.

**The `System.exit` method halts the execution of the current thread and all others dead in their tracks.** When `System.exit` is called, the virtual machine performs two cleanup tasks before shutting down.

First, it executes all shutdown hooks that have been registered with`Runtime.addShutdownHook`. This is useful to release resources external to the VM. Use shutdown hooks for behavior that must occur before the VM exits.

The second cleanup task performed by the VM when `System.exit` is called
concerns finalizers. If either `System.runFinalizersOnExit` or its evil twin
`Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit` has been called, the VM runs the finalizers on
all objects that have not yet been finalized. These methods were deprecated a long
time ago and with good reason. Never call `System.runFinalizersOnExit` or
`Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit` for any reason: They are among the most
dangerous methods in the Java libraries. Calling these methods can result in finalizers being run on live objects while other threads are concurrently manipulating
them, resulting in erratic behavior or deadlock.

In summary, `System.exit` stops all program threads immediately; it does not
cause finally blocks to execute, but it does run shutdown hooks before halting
the VM. Use shutdown hooks to terminate external resources when the VM shuts
down. It is possible to halt the VM without executing shutdown hooks by calling
`System.halt`, but this method is rarely used.

Answer (score 11):

In a file called `A.java`

```
class Con {
    String hi = "\n\nHello World\n\n";
}
```

You just have to compile the program on Windows. Not run it. :-P

Comment: This works because `CON` has special meaning on Windows, right?

Comment: This also prints whole lot of other stuffs too. What is "Con" by the way? It doesn't let name the file as "Con.java". +1.

Comment: -1 Providing a platform-specific solution to a problem in a platform-independent language is incorrect.

Comment: @gurung CON is an old keyword used in DOS and carried forward into Windows as a shortcut for CONsole.  You could copy a filename to CON and it would print on the screen.  PRN is another keyword like this.  I recently had problems storing stock data in folders because I used the stock name as the folder name and there was a stock called "CON".  Windows still won't let you create a folder with this name.  It says "The specified device name is invalid."

Comment: @ErickRobertson Given the nature of the question, I don't think they were looking for a best practice solution.

Comment: When asking "How to print message on console without using main() method?" in an interview, they're not looking for a best practice solution?  It didn't say they were a Microsoft shop in the question, or did I miss something?

Comment: @ErickRobertson exactly. All questions on Stackoverflow based on interview questions, I’ve seen so far, are either, irrelevant, based on wrong premises, or expecting an answer that’s either, actually wrong or discouraged practice. It seems, interviewers really like to ask trick questions about irrelevant corner cases or just want to show off with irrelevant knowledge, which sometimes even turns out to be outdated or wrong (who will ever tell them when they’re wrong?). See just this question, what’s the practical use of it?

Answer (score 8):

You could define a custom class loader that prints your message :

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    public MyClassLoader(ClassLoader other) {
         super(other);
         System.out.println("Hi there");
         System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Then run the java command :

`java -Djava.system.class.loader=MyClassLoader`

(don't need to add a class as parameter)

Answer (score 6):

```
class MainMethodNot
{
    static
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Because the static initializer block is executed when the class is first loaded, we can print out “Hello World” without writing a main method. The execution is stopped using “System.exit()” command. So, we prevent “main method not found” error. 
It's quite a tricky question

Answer (score 3):

It was possible till java 6 to use System.out.println(); without main().
From java 7 onwards, it is not possible to do it with static block. It will still ask for main method in main class.

Comment: yes I have seen in many places, but I am not clear  why not executing in jdk7 and later version, if you can give more details on this that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use static block too, it can be done following way

```
public class NoMain {

    private static final int STATUS = getStatus();

    private static int getStatus() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!");
        System.exit(0);
        return 0;
    }

}
```

However, please note that this is for Java 6 version. Its [not working in Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699087/why-java-7-version-does-not-support-to-run-program-without-main-method?lq=1) which is said to be supported in Java 8. I tried with JDK 1.8.0_77-b03, which is still not working

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can print a message to console without using main().

Create a test with JUnit and execute it:

```
@Test
public printTest()   {
   System.out.println("myprint");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one of the way is static block but in previous version of JDK not in JDK 1.7.

```
class Withoutmain{  
 static{  
  System.out.println("Message: Your message can be print on console without main() method");  
  System.exit(0);  
 }  
}
```

Output:Message: Your message can be print on console without main() method (if not JDK7)

Output:Error: Main method not found in class A3, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)

[Reference](http://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java#staticwithoutmain)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn't work in the latest update of java 8. You can call it a bug fix according to them, but as far as I believe on my current knowledge this can't be called as a bug fix because it also lead to few conceptual changes too in java programming.