# How can you run a Java program without main method?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing message on Console without using main() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605137/printing-message-on-console-without-using-main-method)

Can someone suggest how can a JAVA program run **without** writing a **main method**..

For eg:

```
System.out.println("Main not required to print this");
```

How can the above line be printed on console **without** using the **public static void main(String arg[])** in the class.

Comment: I hope this is just out of curiosity, and you don't intend to do this in a real program... right?

Comment: @DanielPryden Out of curiosity why/how did you think to ask this question? Should OP have posted something convoluted to make you understand exactly what they were doing? The question seems completely valid and the idea is easily extended to do any code one may want to run. Again, why/how did you think of this question?

Comment: I don't know why you are asking, but just in case it's because you really just want code to work like that... give Groovy a look.  It runs Java code and would run the line put in your question correctly even if it was the only line in the file.  I use it for experimenting with Java syntax all the time since it's so much less boilerplate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Up until JDK6, you could use a [static initializer block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) to print the message. This way, as soon as your class is loaded the message will be printed. The trick then becomes using another program to load your class.

```java
public class Hello {
  static {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
  }
}
```

Of course, you can run the program as `java Hello` and you will see the message; however, the command will also fail with a message stating:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

**[Edit]** as noted by others, you can avoid the NoSuchmethodError by simply calling `System.exit(0)` immediately after printing the message.

As of JDK6 onward, you no longer see the message from the `static` initializer block; [details here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/main-method-compulsory-java/).

Comment: So, I must use a static block in this case.
Static block it is then.
Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: not working for me... java version is 1.8.0_65

Answer (score 38):

Up to and including **Java 6** it was possible to do this using the [Static Initialization Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) as was pointed out in the question [Printing message on Console without using main() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605137/printing-message-on-console-without-using-main-method). For instance using the following code:

```
public class Foo {
    static {
         System.out.println("Message");
         System.exit(0);
    } 
}
```

The `System.exit(0)` lets the program exit before the JVM is looking for the `main` method, otherwise the following error will be thrown:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

In **Java 7**, however, **this does not work anymore**, even though it compiles, the following [error](http://ideone.com/WMQkH) will appear when you try to execute it:

> The program compiled successfully, but main class was not found.
>   Main class should contain method: public static void main (String[] args).

Here an alternative is to write your own launcher, this way you can define entry points as you want.

In the article [JVM Launcher](https://web.archive.org/web/20140311103404/http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17352/JVM-Launcher) you will find the necessary information to get started:

> This article explains how can we create a Java Virtual Machine
>   Launcher (like java.exe or javaw.exe). It explores how the Java
>   Virtual Machine launches a Java application. It gives you more ideas
>   on the JDK or JRE you are using. This launcher is very useful in
>   Cygwin (Linux emulator) with Java Native Interface. This article
>   assumes a basic understanding of JNI.

Comment: Hi @platzhirsch, searching for the ways to run an application other than main methods, I followed this article, but the link you mentioned here for information on JVM Launcher doesn't exist anymore.                                                                                               **Can you please help in this**                                                                    I have spent quite a time on net to find it myself but unable to know how to start.

Comment: @PrakrutiPathik Thank god the Internet Archive is still up and running. Here you go: https://web.archive.org/web/20140311103404/http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17352/JVM-Launcher

Comment: That was fast and smart. Thanks...

Comment: In Java 7, `Error: Could not find or load main class Test55` appears on running `java Foo`

Answer (score 14):

```
public class X { static {
  System.out.println("Main not required to print this");
  System.exit(0);
}}
```

Run from the cmdline with `java X`.

Answer (score 3):

[Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) from what I remember do not need a main method, though I am not sure they are technically a program.

Comment: Obviously they are programs!