# Java program without main method above JDK 1.6

Tags: java

Is it possible to run a java program without main method ?
How can I execute this Java program in eclipse?

```
public class A {
    static {
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you *tried* executing it? Basically, no - there's no entry point...

Comment: (Also, please pay more attention to the formatting of your post in future - and note that Stack Overflow doesn't handle tabs terribly nicely... use spaces instead.)

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to "run a Java program" without main method.

For example:

- you could create a jUnit test. In that case Eclipse will offer you the option "Run as jUnit Test".
- you can create a class which extends JApplet. In that case Eclipse will offer the option "Run as Java Applet".

Answer (score 1):

Your question is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421542/how-can-you-run-a-java-program-without-main-method), but the answer is :

Use a static initializer block to print the message. This way, as soon as your class is loaded the message will be printed. The trick then becomes using another program to load your class.

```
public class Hello {
  static {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
  }
}
```

Of course, you can run the program as java Hello and you will see the message; however, the command will also fail with a message stating:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

or

```
public class X { static {
  System.out.println("Main not required to print this");
  System.exit(0);
}}
```

Run from the cmdline with `java X`.

Comment: +1, yes he has same question from there.

Comment: Hi user3145373,
public class X { static {
  System.out.println("Main not required to print this");
  System.exit(0);
}}
this program is not running. When I am trying to run this program then it is giving output of last program.