# How can I derive a list of existing classes in a project?

Tags: java

I want to be able to store an array of every class in my project. Is there a simple way to do it so it looks like this?

```
Class<?>[] classes = SomeClass.getClasses();
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
Here's the code for the main class.

```
package game_engine.main;

public abstract class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        //do something
    }
    protected abstract void start(GameSettings settings);
}
```

Comment: Define "every class"

Comment: Could you give some insight as to why you need to do this? [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/520328/5221149)

Comment: I'm trying to create a game engine with with an extendable main class, and a non-static init method.

Comment: And, "every class", doesn't include anything in the jdk (that would be insane). Just in the project (src folder).

Comment: Based on your comment, you may want to [check out this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424612/how-would-one-create-a-custom-jvm-launcher)

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do it, no. Doing this involves scanning the classpath, which is not doable in a portable way. Google's Guava has [`ClassPath`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html), but it explicitly says to not use it for production-critial tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make it done in one-line code. But this may also help:

```
//scan urls that contain 'my.package', include inputs starting with 'my.package', use the default scanners
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package");

//or using ConfigurationBuilder
new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
 .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("my.project.prefix"))
 .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(), 
              new TypeAnnotationsScanner().filterResultsBy(optionalFilter), ...),
 .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().includePackage("my.project.prefix"))
 ...);
```

Detail：https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

Comment: I've tried using reflections before, but it didn't clone from git, the classes weren't able to be imported and it intellij couldn't import it. How do I add a github repository to a project?

Comment: You are not using maven or gradle?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: It‘s Maven in 5 Minutes.  Another alternative is to build the sourcecode as a jar and then add the jar to the classpath. But using maven is a better way.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: Hello, have you fix it?