# Does java internally creates the object of the class which is holding the main method?

Tags: java, jvm, javac, jit

As we know that if we want to create an `object` of the `class` we need to do something:

```
class MyClass{
// ...
}
```

And to create its `object` we do:

```
MyClass MyObj = new MyClass();
```

Now if we want to create a program in java we need to have a `main` method inside the `class` and that `class` should have the same name as the file name.

For example:

```
// file MyFile.java
public class MyFile{
    public static void main(String[] args){
      // ...
    }
}
```

Now the question is that whether the object of `MyFile` class will also be created internally by `java` when this program runs in order to start the execution of the java file by calling the `main` method or does it calls the `main` method statically as:

```
MyFile.main(String[] args);
```

And what will be the case if I have the class(es) in `MyFile` class as:

```
public class MyFile{

    class HelloWorld{
        // ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or have non-static properties and methods as:

```
public class MyFile{

    int x = 10;

    public void MyWorld(){
        // ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // ...
    }

    int y = 10;

    public void ByeWorld(){
        // ...
    }

}
```

Etc etc.

Now, what will be the scenario? Will `java` internally creates the object of the `MyFile` class? What actions `java` will perform in these type of situations in order to both run the program with the help of `main` method and as well as also to load the other things before and after of the `main` method? What will be the actions performed by the `java` internally in these situations?

Comment: Java compiler doesn't create objects it creates byte code. Java **runtime** creates objects if needed

Comment: the method is `static` so belongs to the `class` not a instance of the class, thus is available when the class is loaded by the classloader and does not require an instance.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471431/does-creating-instance-of-the-same-class-in-the-main-mathod-creates-two-instance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No instance of the class is created automatically when the JVM starts. The `main` method is just invoked statically - that's why it has to be static in the first place.

The class is *initialized*, so if you have a static initializer, *that* will be executed before the `main` method, but no instance of the class will be constructed. There's no need to do so, and it would introduce unnecessary complications. (What would you expect to happen if you only included constructors with parameters, for example?)

For more details of JVM startup, see [chapter 12 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-12.html).

Comment: So, it means that the jvm jumps inside the `public class MyFile{` and start the execution from here?  no need to create instances?

Comment: @SunnyKhan: No, why do you think it *would* need to create an instance? You don't need to create an instance of a class to execute a static method anywhere else - why would startup be different?

Comment: So, the jvm jumps from `public class MyFile{` point and start loading all the members from here and fires the `main` method when it encounters it, is I am right?

Comment: @SunnyKhan You seem to confuse the definition and initialization of the class with creating instances of that class. You need the class initialized to call main, but you don't need an instance of that class (as main is static).

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Sir you don't get me. Basically, I know that we don't need to create its instance, I am actually asking about the `JVM` what `JVM` will do in these situations internally? Whether it will call the static method `main` directly if yes then what about the other members of `MyFile` class in the examples of the question, how these will be created since these are not static, so, whether the `JVM` will create instance internally in these situations, or how it will handle this situation? Asking about the `JVM`, but not about the programmer!!!

Comment: Since `classes` are not called directly but the `static` methods can be called by the `class` name reference, but what about the `non-static` members, these cannot be called without the `class` instance `object`, so, how `JVM` will handle this situation? Or does the `JVM` starts the execution from `public class MyFile{` point and collect everything without creating `MyFile` class instance `object` and fires the `main` method when it encounters `main` method during collection of members from the `MyFile` class?

Comment: @SunnyKhan Accessing anything in a class requires first *loading* a class, using a *classloader*, going through a detailed process defined by the Java specs. For example, security checks are made during loading to verify the integrity of the class. And static initializers are executed, as mentioned in the Answer. I suspect you’ll find satisfaction by learning about the class loading process.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53890332/7294647), we can use a code example to prove that an instance of the enclosing class is **not** created when the `main` method is invoked:

```
public class Test {
    public Test() {
        System.out.println("Test2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

The output of this program is simply:

```
Test
```

If an instance were created, you would see `Test2` printed to the console as well.

Comment: `Test2` method needs return type `void` so it will work without any errors.

Comment: @SunnyKhan That's not a method, it's a constructor for the `Test` class.

Comment: You are right, I was doing the test in my file where the class name was different than the `Test2` so it looks method to me that's why it returns an error.

Comment: @SunnyKhan I changed the class' name to `Test` to avoid confusion!