# without main class in java throws error while running

Tags: java

```
public class trial { 
    static {
        System.out.println("Main not required to print this");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This code still throws an error as

> Error: Main method not found in class trial, please define the main method as:
>      public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application**

There were posts saying that it will work in **java 1.9** but it doesn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421542/how-can-you-run-a-java-program-without-main-method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) 1. Show how you were trying to run the class. 2. Link to and quote (in the *question*) the post that you think says something changed in JDK 9.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the page that said so?

Comment: Who told you that **Main method is not required to print this**...? Main method is mandatory to start the application. Once it's been started, all your static blocks will be executed when the Class Loader loads the relevant class.