# Printing hello world without main method

Tags: java

I am using Eclipse.  I am trying to make a program that doesn't contain a `main` function, but will still print `Hello, World`:

```
  public class Q 
  {
     static 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.exit(0);
    }
  }
```

But this program is not giving me expected result.An error is coming which says that main method is not found in class Q.  Where I am making a mistake?

Comment: you are not including the main method.

Comment: Java requires that you have a main method; there's no two ways about it.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: Your program must have entry point.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11421618/745924). It looks like the trick you are trying to do no longer works in Java 7.

Comment: -1; each and every tutorial tells us that we need a main method to run a Java application.

Comment: Ah, but there is more to this question that meets the eye. Don't be so quick to downvote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing message on Console without using main() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605137/printing-message-on-console-without-using-main-method)

Answer (score 6):

You still need to *run* the program for the static initialization block to execute, which you cannot do without an appropriate `main` method (as of Java 7<sup>1</sup>). Now, that's not to say `main` needs to actually contain any code:

```
class Q {
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Your code *actually works in Java 6 and below* - you don't need a `main` method. This is because the `static` initialization block executes *before* a `main` method is searched for. But, in your case, you exit the program at the end of that block with `System.exit(0)`, and so Java never looks for `main` and you don't receive an error.

Comment: This code is working on Notepad++,,but it is not working on eclipse ..you can also try this code then answer plz

Comment: i dont know why it is not working on eclipse..did you tried  it yet'

Comment: Some run environments, especially test ones, may have different-than-normal rules for program entry.

Comment: but why i am not getting the result ,,Why these all people are saying that without main method you can't  print the hello world .I think they haven't heard about static block

Comment: Works for me in Eclipse.  But it may have a timing issue: if System.out hasn't been flushed, buffered output is discarded.  So I would recommend adding a `System.out.flush();`

Comment: Why my question got -3 remarks, all guys except Arshaji and CPerkins  could understand my thougt thats not my problem. ARshaji and CPerkins plz explain this program to those guys who dont know how does it work

Answer (score 1):

Every Java Application Program must contain a class with main method in it. So your error will persist until you declare a main method inside one of the classes in your program.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. Your program MUST contain the main method, or the system doesnt know witch piece of code to run.

Comment: open your eclipse first and run this program first,then give your opinion

Comment: OK, i admit i dont even have eclipse installed, but programming in IDE and developing acctual program can be different, and even if you manage to trick your program to run without the main method, it surely isnt the proper way to do it and no one can guarantee your program would run on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you are trying to run class that does not have `main` method (exactly as you explained).

JVM is looking for public static void main method that accepts array o `String` as an argument as an entry point to any program.

Answer (score 0):

> "Java programs start executing at the main method, which has the
>   following method heading: 
>   
> public static void main(String[] args)"
>   
> (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#Java)

You should alter your class to be something similar to what I've put below.

```
public class Q 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.exit(0);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The program will run for this code

You just have to compile it by using **javac Hello.java** and then execute it for output by **java Hello.java** on your console.
Make sure java compiler and everything is done corectly.
.

Thank you!!
Have a nice day.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sql.*;
public class Emsa
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
        int ch;
try
{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","hr","hr");
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from Empdirc");
while(rs.next())           
            do
            {
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("ENTER EMPLOYEE DETAILS:");
                System.out.println("1.Insert Record into the Table");
                System.out.println("2.Update The Existing Record.");
        System.out.println("3.Display all the Records from the Table");
                System.out.println("4.Check PRIVILAGE LEAVE and Casual Leaves");
                System.out.println("5.Exit");
                System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");

                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                ch=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                  switch(ch)
                {
                case 1:

                System.out.println("1.INSERT EMPLOYEE ID.");
                int num= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("2.INSERT EMPLOYEE NAME");
                String ename=br.readLine();
                System.out.println("3.INSERT EMPLOYEE DESIGNATION");
                String desig=br.readLine();
                System.out.println("4.INSERT EMPLOYEE DATEOFBIRTH");
                String dob=br.readLine();
                System.out.println("5.INSERT EMPLOYEE PHONE NO OR ANY CONTACT");
                String mob= br.readLine();
                System.out.println("6.INSERT EMPLOYEE EMAIL ID");
                String email= br.readLine();
                System.out.println("7.INSERT EMPLOYEE SALARY");
                String sal=br.readLine();
                System.out.println("8.INSERT EMPLOYEE paid LEAVES");
                String pl=br.readLine();
                System.out.println("9.INSERT EMPLOYEE CASUAL LEAVES");
                String cl=br.readLine();
                System.out.println("10.INSERT EMPLOYEE FINAL SALARY");
                String fi= br.readLine();
                System.out.println("11.STATUS");
                String s=br.readLine();


                    String sql="insert into EmpDirc values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement p=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    p.setInt(1,num);
                    p.setString(2,ename);
                    p.setString(3,desig);
                    p.setString(4,dob);
                    p.setString(5,mob);
                    p.setString(6,email);
                    p.setString(7,sal);
                    p.setString(8,pl);
                    p.setString(9,cl);
                    p.setString(10,fi);
                    p.setString(11,s);
public static boolean abcd(String str)
    {
        int x;
        for(int mob= 0 ; mob < str.length() ; mob++)
        {
            x = (int)str.charAt(mob);
            if( x < 10 || x > 0)
            return false;    
        }
        return true;
    }
                    p.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("Record Added");

                    //p.close();
                    //con.close();
                    break;


            case 2:
                    System.out.println("UPDATE EMPLOYEE id : ");
                    int emnum=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("UPDATE EMPLOYEE DESIGNATION : ");
                    String emdesig=br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("UPDATE EMPLOYEE PHONE: ");
                    String emphn=br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("UPDATE EMPLOYEE EMAIL: ");
                    String emmail=br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("UPDATE EMPLOYEE SALARY: ");
                    String emsal=br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("UPDATE EMPLOYEE PL: ");
                    String empl=br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("UPDATE EMPLOYEE CL: ");
                    String emcl=br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("UPDATE EMPLOYEE FINAL SALARY: ");
                    String emfi=br.readLine();
                    sql="update EmpDirc set Desig=?, Mob=? , Email=?, Sal=? , fi=? where Eid=?";
                    PreparedStatement  ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);

                    ps.setString(1,emdesig);
                    ps.setString(2,emphn);
                    ps.setString(3,emmail);
                    ps.setString(4,emsal);
                    //ps.setString(5,empl);
                    //ps.setString(6,emcl);
                    ps.setString(5,emfi);
                ps.setInt(6,emnum);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("Record Updated");
                    //p.close();
                    //con.close();
                    break;

case 3 :    System.out.println("Displaying the Data ");

           //Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
         ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("select * from Empdirc");
while(res.next())
            System.out.println("Eid"+res.getInt(1)+"Ename "+res.getString(2)+"Design "+res.getString(3)+"Dob "+res.getString(4)+"Mobile no."+res.getString(5)+"Email "+res.getString(6)+"Salary "+res.getString(7));
                   break;
case 4 : System.out.println("CALCULATING");
            sql="update EmpDirc set Pl=?, Cl=? where Estatus=?";

                    PreparedStatement pes=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pes.setInt(1,15);
                pes.setInt(2,07);
                 pes.setString(3,"permanent");
            pes.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Record Updated");



                    case 5:
                    System.exit(0);
break;

                    default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
                    break;
}
}while(ch!=2);


con.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}
}
}
```