# Java program without main method

Tags: java, eclipse

For my class I need to write code that adds up the numbers 1-100 which will produce the number 5050. He told us not to use a main method and use a for loop. Is a main method 'public static void main (String[] args)' or something else. I am just still very confused on what exactly the main method is. Here is the code I have so far that works

```
public class SumAndAverageForLoop{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int sum = 0; 
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) sum += i; 
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
    }
}
```

From what I read more and after talking to some other kids in the class they said I need to make another class with a main method that calls this class but how do you call one class from another?

How to call one class from another that has a main method?

Comment: In your code, yes, you have that "main method"; the JDK requires it to be able to run a program. The fact that you use a for loop or not is irrelevant to the fact that you use it in a main() or not. I don't really understand what your teacher is up to.

Comment: The requirement to not use a main method is really weird. But then again, some teachers are lame. So, screw it: go ahead and write a main method, and invoke your AddOneToOneHundred method from it, to make sure it works, and then remove the main method before turning in the assignment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing message on Console without using main() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605137/printing-message-on-console-without-using-main-method) (but note that this will not work in versions 7 and above)

Answer (score 2):

Yes the `public static void main(String[] args)` signature is the main method.

It sounds like you're writing library style code.  So just create a method with a meaningful name for what your code does. Like `AddOnetoOneHundred` or similar.

You can create a method like this:

```
public static int CountUp() {
    // code that was in your main method before
}
```

Double check your assignment, your teaching might have specified a class and method name and already has a program that will test your code.

Comment: How exactly do you create a method?

Answer (score 1):

A main method is fundamental to any given program as the Java compiler searches for the method as a starting point of execution. However, you are trying to make a utility class so:

```
class SumAndAverageForLoop {

    // no main method

    public static int sum() {
        int sum = 0; 
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) sum += i; 
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
    }
}

class MainClassProgram {

    // main in another class

    public static void main() {
        SumAndAverageForLoop.sum();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a method to do the calculation. The idea is create code that is unit testable.

```
public class SumAndAverageForLoop{
  public static void main (String[] args) {
      int returned = SumUp(1, 100);
      System.Out.Println("sum is " + returned);
  }
  public int SumUp(int startInt, int endInt) {
      int sum = 0;
      if (endInt > startInt) {
         for (int i = startInt; i <= endInt; i++) sum += i; 
      }
      return sum;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

Yes, that (`public static void main (String[] args)`) is the main method.

**Long Answer:**

The main method is the entry point for an application.  Without it, you may have code, but that code must somehow link to a main method or it cannot be ran.  Counter-intuitively, the main method doesn't actually have to be a method.  In C, you can create an integer array called main and execute it.  It will translate the integers into hexadecimal and execute a corresponding Assembly command for each one, iteratively.

If you do what the professor says, you will not be able to test the program as an executable.  He probably has a program made to run your code and test it for him, which is why he doesn't want a main method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure by what your teacher means by, "not using a main method". But you can declare a method outside of you main method and call it from there;

```
public class SumAndAverageForLoop{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        makeSum();
    }

    public static void makeSum() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Also, since one of your comments asked "How to create a method?".

I suggest you read up on some books for beginners. I'd recommend the book Head First Java.