# Why java (>=7 version) does not support to run program without main method?

Tags: java, static, jvm

```java
class WithoutMain {   
       static
       {           
            System.out.println("Without main class!!!");
            System.exit(0);            
       }
}
```

when I am trying to to run above code in java version greater than 7 i am getting below error.
The program compiled successfully, but main class was not found. Main class should contain method: public static void main (String[] args).

can someone please guide me why Java does not support to run program without main after java7

Comment: What does this have to do with the java version? You cant run a program without an entry point.

Comment: just one question, What do you mean with "Java (>=7)"? Did it work for an  older version of java? I mean that the same problem should  arise for any other version of java because an entry point (main method) is also needed.

Comment: @ Ricard Nàcher Roig:- Yes we can run java program without main method with version lower than 7.If you will run above program in lower version than 7 it will give out put "Without main class!!!"

Comment: There's actually a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605137/printing-message-on-console-without-using-main-method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK this change was specific to Java 7. In Java 8 you can do this.  You can't do this in Java 7 as it looks for the method without loading the class first which fails.  In any case, it has been changed back in Java 8.

```
public class Main {
    static {
        System.out.println("Without main class!!! with " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Without main class!!! with 1.8.0_66
```

Note: this will kill the whole program. If you want the program to keep running without a main you can do this

```
public class Main {
    static {
        // do something which starts threads
        System.out.println("Without main class!!! with " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        if (true)
            throw new ThreadDeath();
    }
}
```

This will prevent the error message, but leave background threads running provided there is a non-daemon thread.

Comment: thanks a lot Peter Lawrey for clearing my doubt.

Comment: I am using version 1.8.0_77 but still my program says the main method not found define the main method as public static void main (String[] args). @Peter Lawrey

Answer (score 1):

the static section

```
static
       {           
            System.out.println("Without main class!!!");
            System.exit(0);            
       }
```

will be executed every time the JVM load the class in memory, but if you want to start a java application, you will need a main method, because that it the start point of every java application, if you dont define it, then the JVM will have no idea where to start.

---

you can expand your code and do something like:

```
class WithoutMain {   
       static
       {           
            System.out.println("Static section!!");

       }

      public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println("Main class!!!");
      }   
}
```

and the output will be the static section first and then the code you define in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

Static method is loaded with the class each time the JVM is started and the class is loaded into it, but there is nothing that calls it or outputs its contents inside of the JVM. As every language (that I know), you need a handler for your arguments and in case of Java, it is the `main()` method.